# Custom size integers in MySQL and Sparksee databases

Tags: c++, mysql, integer, bit, sparksee

Is there a way to define a type of integers, that are only 7 bits long? Or at least 1 byte long? I want to replace standard integers stored in database to reduce the size. I am using mainly those databases: MySQL, Sparksee (for graphs). And those languages: C++, Objective-C++. Is using `char` instead of `int` - my best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL supports the `TINYINT` (8 bit), `SMALLINT` (16 bit), `MEDIUMINT` (24 bit), `INT` (32 bit), and `BIGINT` (64 bit) data types.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

The corresponding C language data types are `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, and `int64_t`. There isn't a standard 24-bit data type in C. See this for more information. http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html

These are signed data types. So, for example, `int8_t` has potential values in the range [-128, 127].

You will need a very large number of records in your system for your cost saving from using smaller integers to exceed one dollar US. SSD drives currently cost something less than $0.50 per gigabyte.  Best to spend your time and effort elsewhere.

Comment: I have tens-hundreds of billions values, so this might be useful. Thanks for response.

Comment: According to Sparksee docs, the smallest int size they support is 32 bits. Is it so or there is a hint?